# How to group by some fields and display the first value of another field in oracle?

Tags: oracle, group-by

Here is the table which I am looking at after grouping:

```
DATE:       TEST:   BUILD:  NUM:
17-FEB-14   testA   BUILDA  100
18-FEB-14   testA   BUILDA  20
20-FEB-14   testA   BUILDB  120
```

I am grouping by TEST, BUILD AND DATE.
Problem here is,
some of the subtests on testA on BUILDA, happened to be on 17Feb14, where as some are on 18Feb14.
This splits up the same record as record1 and record2.

What I need is just the total with the first date:

```
DATE:       TEST:   BUILD:  NUM:
17-FEB-14   testA   BUILDA  120
20-FEB-14   testA   BUILDB  120
```

Is there any way I could achieve this?

The query is a very long one, hence not posting the complete query.
But it looks like:

```
SELECT r.RN_EXECUTION_DATE, t.TESTSETNAME, r.RN_BUILD_VERSION, r.rn_status, 
 COUNT(r.rn_run_id) AS run_count
 FROM table t, table r, (.........) tlf
 WHERE (........)

GROUP BY t.TESTSETNAME,
  r.RN_BUILD_VERSION,
  r.RN_EXECUTION_DATE,
  r.rn_status

ORDER BY t.TESTSETNAME,
  r.RN_BUILD_VERSION  
;
```

Thanking in advance,
Manoj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the aggregate function MIN on your date column:

```
SELECT MIN(r.RN_EXECUTION_DATE), t.TESTSETNAME, r.RN_BUILD_VERSION, r.rn_status, 
 COUNT(r.rn_run_id) AS run_count
 FROM table t, table r, (.........) tlf
 WHERE (........)

GROUP BY t.TESTSETNAME,
  r.RN_BUILD_VERSION,
  r.rn_status

ORDER BY t.TESTSETNAME,
  r.RN_BUILD_VERSION  
;
```